# What's the point of banning abortions where abortion clinics are available in nearby countries?

Tags: abortion

As an example, Ireland currently bans abortions while they are fully legal in the UK. So there is nothing to stop a pregnant Irish woman from taking a plane/ferry to the UK, getting an abortion, and coming back. No visa of any kind is needed for such a trip as in fact Irish citizens have nearly absolute freedom of movement within the Common Travel Area, regardless of EU membership. A quick Google search [reveals](https://www.mariestopes.org.uk/overseas-clients-abortion/irish/costs-payment-how-book/fees-how-much-abortion-irish-women) that such services are commonly offered to Irish women and the prices seem reasonable.

So what's the point of having restrictive laws within Ireland itself? Don't all Irish women who want an abortion get one?

Comment: What's the point of banning prostitution when you can get on a plane and patronize one legally? Or smoke pot? Or any number of things where it's illegal here but not somewhere else? Why just abortion?

Comment: @Machavity abortion is usually a rare necessity and it's not like one does them on a recreational basis. The comparison is not fully valid.

Comment: To keep those lacking resources from accessing what those with means can readily get.

Comment: Those reasonable prices you refer to could be someone's weekly wage, or another person's monthly wage. Reasonable is subjective.

Comment: Ideological bans aren't always about practicality. They can be about stamping out perceived evil; the lawmakers feel a moral imperative to act regardless of logical implications of other nearby facilities.

Comment: "Fully legal in the UK" isn't quite accurate. The law outside Northern Ireland requires two registered doctors to agree that the termination is necessary for a set of (relatively lax) criteria. Inside Northern Ireland it requires belief of a serious probable list to long term health. A vote on a 10 minute rule bill to fully decriminalise abortion before the 24th week in England & Wales passed its first reading, but is one of the potential bits of legislation that seems to be going to get lost in the wash in the run up to the election.

Comment: Is the law targeting women or doctors? The UK government had rules in place for issuing passport modifications for people traveling overseas to get gender reassignment surgery to avoid difficulties of not matching the gender on file for at least one leg of the trip, while the surgeries were not available in the UK.

Comment: @origimbo if UK refuses for some reason you still have a choice of numerous EU countries with zero abortion restrictions.

Comment: @JonathanReez The key point though is that a woman seeking an elective abortion in the Republic can't simply cross the land border to the UK, which is going to inflate the difficulty and expense, noted in Carpetsmoker's answer below, getting to Great Britain.

Comment: @K-C My point is that there are many laws where you can avoid them by simply traveling to where they are legal. I'm not sure this can be objectively answered

Comment: @origimbo: They can cross a land border to the United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland. They can't cross a land border to Great Britain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot answer well for the specific situation in Ireland, but there are a few parallel situations in my home country, the United States. There is potent anti-abortion sentiment in the United States, but it is [unconstitutional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roe_v._Wade) to make abortion illegal. Any state passing a law directly banning abortion, can expect to have that law struck down in the courts.

Several states have tried to do an end run around the constitutional protections on abortion by putting extra regulations on abortion clinics. In 2013, the state of Texas [passed a law](http://www.nytimes.com/2013/07/19/us/perry-signs-texas-abortion-restrictions-into-law.html) requiring abortion clinics to meet some difficult requirements, building codes designed for surgical centers, abortion doctors required to have admitting privileges at nearby hospitals, etc. Of the 41 abortion clinics in the state, [19 of them had closed within a year](https://fivethirtyeight.com/features/its-really-hard-to-measure-the-effects-of-abortion-restrictions-in-texas/). In some parts of Texas, the nearest abortion clinic was a 4 hour drive away. This led to a 13% drop in clinic abortions in one year.

**Restricting access to abortion can lead more women to choose not to have a abortion in a clinic.**

Comment: While it is technically true that there is "strong" anti-abortion sentiment in the US, that is a very misleading statement the way it is phrased. Gallup has [polled abortion legality opposition](http://www.gallup.com/poll/1576/abortion.aspx) since Roe, and it has been fairly stable at roughly 30% opposed in only some circumstances, 20% in **all** circumstances, and 50% in no circumstances (iow: Its not the government's place to decide such things). Since the question is about simple legality, it is the 20% you are talking about being "strong" here.

Comment: The anti-abortion sentiment is strong in the south, which includes, Mississippi, my home state, and Texas. For my argument to work, it doesn't have to be strong nationally, it just has to be strong in the Texas state legislature.

Comment: Not actually quibbling with the argument, just that misleading phrasing.

Comment: The anti-abortion sentiment is strong in the sense that it gets laws passed, not necessarily strong in the sense that a lot of people agree with it. I edited the phrasing, but I am going to value conciseness over precision.

Comment: I think the usual shorthand for that is "vocal" rather than "strong". "Potent" works too though, I guess. I do heartily agree with your valuation of conciseness.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  Lack of constitutionality in the US does not explain why *Ireland* would ban abortions.

Answer (score 1):

There are parts of the world where child labour is allowed. Should we lift the laws on child labour because it's allowed in other parts, and we can't fully prevent it from happening regardless of the laws we make here?

Of course not. Child labour is morally wrong, and even though we can't ban child labour fully (e.g. clothes made in sweatshops) we can at least make an attempt. And banning it by law is a part of that.

It's exactly the same with abortion. Of course, whether or not abortion is morally wrong is a much more controversial topic, but it doesn't change the underlying reasoning.

> Don't all Irish women who want an abortion get one?

Probably not, since it's [pretty expensive](https://www.mariestopes.org.uk/overseas-clients-abortion/irish/costs-payment-how-book/fees-how-much-abortion-irish-women) (and this doesn't include the travel costs).

Comment: An employer benefiting from labor, child labor or otherwise, requires ongoing time and effort. I cannot get on a ferry, go to another country, and  hire some child workers on a day trip.